# How to use local file as background image url

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

What should I change to insert a local link to `C:\xampp\htdocs\Folder` instead of the `https://source.unsplash.com/1600x1050/?nature`.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and this is my css

```css
.jumbotron{
    background: 
      linear-gradient(
        rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.25), 
        rgba(125, 250, 250, 0.45)
      ),
      url(https://source.unsplash.com/1600x1050/?nature);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color:white !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that `C:\xampp\htdocs\` is the root of your web site, meaning that relative URL `/` in your HTML, CSS and JavaScript files will probably point to `C:\xampp\htdocs\`. If so, URL `/Folder/pic.jpg` might just work for you, since that will internally translate to file `C:\xampp\htdocs\Folder\pic.jpg`.

```css
.jumbotron{
    background: 
      linear-gradient(
        rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.25), 
        rgba(125, 250, 250, 0.45)
      ),
      url("/Folder/pic.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color:white !important;
}
```

Comment: An absolute directory should also work if you use forward slashes. It does on my Chromium browsers, anyway. I don't know if that's expected standard behavior.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance . . . I guess you could indeed use absolute paths in HTML/CSS files, but IMHO such absolute paths only seem to have disadvantages. I guess they will break if you decide to host such files on a web server. (If not, they might reveal information about your file system, which can be considered to be a security concern.) Absolute paths also tend to be longer than relative paths. They are often OS-dependent as well. So even if they function properly in a technical sense, they will limit the flexibility, portability and maintainability of your HTML/CSS file(s) in a practical sense.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance . . . Besides that, the use of absolute paths in HTML/CSS files might probably be worth a discussion on its own. Strictly speaking, the OP just asked for a fitting local alternative of a URL to an external resource (which I assume to already exist in the local `C:\xampp\htdocs\Folder` directory), so I consider a discussion about absolute paths to be off-topic here.

Comment: Agreed, hosting on a relative path is definitely the more flexible solution here.